# Web standard/convention for light/dark themeing of a website?

Tags: web-development, usability, theme, standards, user-friendly

The option to switch between a light and a dark theme is getting more and more popular.

However, every site implements this feature differently. It could be useful for power users to have a global option in the browser to switch between light and dark themes which gets applied to all websites.

As far as I know there is no standard (tag, attribute, handler, css-attribute, etc.) which would define such a behavior. Even if there isn't, is there a convention between web developers which is similar to this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not [about webmastering](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This *may* be a better fit at [ux.se]. Be sure to read their [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help) before posting to make sure your question meets their requirements.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the hint. I wasn't sure if it fits here. According to Wikipedia, webmasters include web-developers too, that's why I asked it here. If you have the necessary permissions, would you mind moving the question to User Experience? I read through the FAQ and it should fit. Regarding the tags (if I can't edit them once the question is moved), could you use themes, usability, websites, standards, user-centered-design instead of the current ones there? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: PPS: I deemed this question part of web-development, not web-design, since it is concerned with the implementation. But I agree, its mainly about user experience.

Comment: As I see that you have been active meanwhile, I'll take this as a non-verbal "do it yourself". Okay. Duplication is not my problem.